# A Star Algorithm most efficient path

Tags: algorithm

I tried writing A star algorithm with diagonals and heuristics of straight distance between two points. However, the path isn't shortest in a certain case like this
[image]

Going (2,2) -> (3,2) -> (4,2) -> (5,2) would be faster, but it chose to cut up.

I can't figure out whats wrong with my understanding, because this is how it would actually work when I think it out too.

My understanding:

1. Starts from (1,1) finds (2,2) to be best
2. Finds (3,3) to be best, finds (4,3) to be best as you can't cut corners
3. Finds (5,3) to be best, but calculates the f value of (5,2) as X
4. Can't go to (6,2) and calculates f(5,2) as Y > X so path backtracks to (4,3)
5. Since (5,3) is no longer in the open set, chooses the next best (5,2)
6. Rest of the path is fine, nothing backtracks as no "Dead-ends" were met.

What it should have realized is that f(5,2) is lower than (4,2) which is lower than (3,2) which is never calculated from since it chose to take (3,3)

What exactly is wrong with this?

Edit: Step cost is 1 for horizontal/vertical and sqrt(2) for diagonals

Comment: Whats the actual cost to go from (2,2) to (3,3)? Is it 1 or sqrt(2)?

Comment: sqrt(2). The heuristics would be sqrt(4^2 + 2^2)

Comment: In this case there is a bug in your implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry? The steps I listed was what would happen in my mind regardless of the code, so... Could you tell me which step in my reasoning was wrong please?

Comment: A*, if done correctly, finds the shortest path. The path you have shown is not the shortest. In your example reasoning you did not show all the nodes in the open set so it's difficult to tell where it went wrong.

Comment: All the nodes in the open set? So are you saying I should have calculated f(4,2) from (3,2) before going down (4,3)? Wouldn't that make the same thing as flood filling?
Right now I have a stack<node> which gets pushed a list of the adjacent nodes in descending order, so it goes down the path most efficient until it finds otherwise (like a tail recursive function) (sorry I'm not too familiar with Stack Overflow rules, is this discussion okay?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134651/discussion-between-ericchen1248-and-henry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Henry in the comments, the reasoning is off because (4,3) -> (5,2) would have a higher f value than (2,2) -> (3,2), so it should instead go down (3,2)

I.E. the next node to evaluate is chosen from a list of sorted open nodes, instead of a list of nodes with groups of values sorted upon entering (not a stack with a sorted listed added to it)